# AWS OpsWorks - setup_failed and eternal pending logs

Tags: devops, aws-opsworks

I'm trying to create an Q.A. stack at OpsWorks. My knowledge in OpsWorks are very superficial, so I began creating a stack with 1 layer and 1 instance. I used only AWS recipes to create an PHP Application layer:
[[IMG]](https://snag.gy/nK4kyj.jpg)

When I try to boot my first instance, I got the error "start_failed". My problem is: I can't see any logs to find out what is going on, because it keep in pending status forever:
[[IMG]](https://snag.gy/2AYUgL.jpg)

I already tried to access via SSH and AWS CLI, but I still can't get any log.

Comment: Please include the relevant code within your question as code. Linking to external resources hurts our ability to answer your question, and using images for code or error messages makes searching for similar errors impossible. If you have questions please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

If your instance is in a start_failed state, this can indicate quite a few possible issues. A lot of issues are covered in this specific [troubleshooting documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/linux-instance-start-opsworks/).

Since you appear to be able to SSH into the instance, you're going to want to check the OpsWorks Agent logs for errors. These are available(with elevated privileges) in:
/var/log/aws/opsworks